# Data coming from backend is stored in object but not accessible in object properties

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

Data coming from backend is stored in object but when i tries to print in using object properties its showing undefined. Here is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it3Ic.png)

my code:

```
this.documentService.getDocumentbyId(this.id).subscribe(
data => {
this.upmDoc=data;
console.log("UPM Data Fetched:",this.upmDoc);
console.log("Name:",this.upmDoc.name);
console.log("Symbolic Name:",this.upmDoc.symbolicName);
console.log("Object Store:",this.upmDoc.objectStore);
console.log("Active:",this.upmDoc.active);
},
error => console.log(error)
);
```

Comment: Provide your response in json format not image

Comment: You need to take a closer look at the server response. `upmDoc` has some really weird keys, your backend seems to be feeding you broken data. You have `upmDoc['Status']`, `upmDoc['Document Details: ']`...

Comment: upmDoc have name, object store and symbolic name properties. the JSON i am getting is in string format.I want to extract above properties from json and use them

Comment: {
    "Status": "Success",
    "Document Details: ": "id:- 102nameApplications Store objectStore:- Focus Corp symbolicName:- ApplicationsStore",
    "Message": "Document retrive successfully:"
}
JSON Response

Answer (score 0):

Its better to provide the response JSON instead of image to make sure where the problem is.

It looks like your service return HTTP Response not the body of the response. try to access the body of the data instead. replace the third line with:

```
this.upmDoc = data.body;
```

or

```
this.upmDoc = data["Document Details"];
```

based on your returned JSON.

Comment: {
    "Status": "Success",
    "Document Details: ": "id:- 102nameApplications Store objectStore:- Focus Corp symbolicName:- ApplicationsStore",
    "Message": "Document retrive successfully:"
}
This is the JSON object I am getting , among which i want name, object store and symbolic name properties

Comment: Your Json return ["Document Details"] as string instead of object. to read it you will have to manipulate string and it's not 100% sure to read the data correctly.check this stackblitz link [link]https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-b53ifb

Comment: Thank you...I tried the same, and it worked.

Comment: If it solved your question please mark it as solved.